# R - Trying to add factor analysis scores to my original data

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I ran a polychoric exploratory factor analysis and I'm trying to assign factor scores to each case in my original data.  I've found a few suggestions for how to do this, but each one results in the following error:

> no applicable method for 'factor.scores' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Two methods are producing the same error, so I think the problem might be more general.  I've tried:

## compute factor scores

myData.EFA$scores <- factor.scores(myData,myData.EFA)

and the general approach also yields the same error when I run without polychoric transformation

## factor scores

scores <- factor.scores(myData, fit)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `factor.scores()` command does not directly produce columns of factor scores for each of the cases. For that reason, you cannot directly append the output to your data.frame object. To do that, you need to get the factor scores from the `factor.scores()` output in an additional step. Then your can add them to your dataset. See below for an example of how to get the factor scores using the `bfi` example dataset.

```
    library(psych)
    bfi <- bfi[,1:24]                 #select variables to include in fa
    fit <- fa(bfi, 2)                 #estimate model with 2 factors
    fs <- factor.scores(bfi, fit)     #obtain factor scores
    fs <- fs$scores                   #get the columns of factor scores for each case
    bfi <- cbind(bfi,fs)              #append factor scores to dataset (you can also 
                                      #use merge()) or something comparable.
```

This also works if you use `fa.poly()` for your factor analysis, but the structure of the `fa.poly()` output object is slightly different, so you need to specify more clearly where the required fa output is located when running `factor.scores()`. This is located in the`$fa` section of the output object. See below for an example using again the `bfi` dataset.

```
    library(psych)
    bfi <- bfi[,1:24]                      #select variables to include in fa
    fit2 <-fa.poly(bfi, 2)                 #estimate model with 2 factors
    fs2 <- factor.scores(bfi, fit2$fa)     #obtain factor scores
    fs2 <- fs$scores                       #get the columns of factor scores
    bfi <- cbind(bfi,fs2)                  #append factor scores to your dataset
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Bless you.  Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: ```fa.poly``` has been deprecated and all its functionalities are now available in the ```fa``` function. Hence, the second chunk of code described in the response above is no longer necessary. Oddly, in my own EFA using a polychoric matrix, I was not able to merge the 2 factor scores with the original dataset because ```cbind``` did not recognize the factor scores output matrix as 2 separate columns. Therefore, the numbers of rows in the original Dataframe did not match the number of rows of the factor scores. The solution was to convert the factor scores object to a Dataframe before merging.